# Delete used line in csv and move to an other csv file

Tags: python, csv, writer

I'm currently skipping used data lines but i actually want to move the used dataline to a new csv file so that i have a clear divider between used and unused data.

i'm currently using:

```
data = []
with open(path_to_csv_file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        data.append(line)

print(data)
```

what i'm looking for:

1. Read data
2. print data
3. move data to new "used" csv file
4. delete used data line
5. repeat

Comment: When you say 'delete used data line' do you mean delete it from the `path_to_csv_file` file being read or from memory?

Comment: What's your question? The code you've shown reads a csv file. What code have you written to actually do the thing you mention in your post? What is the problem with that code?

Comment: i mean delete it from the file it's being read from

Comment: There is no real function to delete a portion of a file other than truncating from the end. Your best option is to keep track how far you get through the file and then copy the remainder on top of the original file.

Comment: Your other option, perhaps, is use the [mmap library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) to treat the file as an in-memory string.

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively delete a row from a CSV by reading from the original and then just not writing to the new CSV. Then, replace the original file with the new.

If we start with this original.csv:

```
| Name  | Department   |
|-------|--------------|
| Alice | Finance      |
| Bobby | Marketing    |
| Chuck | Marketing    |
| Daryl | Mailing Svcs |
```

We can effectively move any row with Marketing to a new marketing CSV, and preserve other rows, by:

1. opening both output-marketing.csv and output-new.csv for writing, and creating csv.writers for each
2. reading from original

   1. copying the header (if you have one)
   2. for each row (of data):

      1. writing to output-marketing.csv if Marketing
      2. else, writing to output-new.csv:

```py
import csv

f_mkt = open("output-marketing.csv", "w", newline="")
writer_mkt = csv.writer(f_mkt)

f_new = open("output-new.csv", "w", newline="")
writer_new = csv.writer(f_new)


f_in = open("original.csv", newline="")
reader = csv.reader(f_in)

header = next(reader)
writer_mkt.writerow(header)
writer_new.writerow(header)

for row in reader:
    if row[1] == "Marketing":
        writer_mkt.writerow(row)
    else:
        writer_new.writerow(row)
```

and that gives us output-marketing.csv:

```
| Name  | Department |
|-------|------------|
| Bobby | Marketing  |
| Chuck | Marketing  |
```

and output-new.csv:

```
| Name  | Department   |
|-------|--------------|
| Alice | Finance      |
| Daryl | Mailing Svcs |
```

If you have a script this simple, that exits as soon as it's done reading/writing, you don't need to bother with closing the files yourself, or with `with open(...) as x` statements: Python will close any open files as it exits your program/script.

Once your confident in the process you can add some code to move new to the original:

```py
import shutil

shutil.move("output-new.csv", "original.csv")
```